# Ionic 3 component insert images

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to build a component that inserts different images in the content. For example, I have 3 images and I want using on various contents.

My **image-component.ts**
 is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logo',
  templateUrl: 'app-logo.html'
})
export class AppLogoComponent {

  image1: string;
  image2: string;
  image3: string;

  constructor() {

    this.image1 = '../../assets/imgs/img1.png';
    this.image2 = '../../assets/imgs/img2.png';
    this.image3 = '../../assets/imgs/img3.png';

  }

}
```

**image-component.html**

```
<ion-img [src]="image1"></ion-img>
<ion-img [src]="image2"></ion-img>
<ion-img [src]="image3"></ion-img>
```

But, if I try insert the component in the page that way, It show error.

```
  <image-component>
    <ion-img [src]="image1"></ion-img>
  </image-component>
```

Someone can help me the know where is the error?

Thanks!

Comment: What error? :-)

Comment: 'image-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'image-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'image-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  </p>

  [ERROR ->]<image-component>
    <ion-img [src]="imageColor"></ion-img>
  </image-component>
"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@14:2

Comment: Try searching this error on google, I'm pretty sure that the first result will solve your problem.

Comment: well, I already search for this and don't is working for me